# Should I call free when creating a new pointer pointing to an area originally created by malloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

In the code below, do I need to "free" the pointer pointing to an area of memory that was allocated using malloc? Isn't it sufficient to free the main pointer?

```
char * parentArray = malloc( 10 * sizeof(char));
char * miniArray   = &parentArray [1];
free(myArr);
// free(miniArray) ?
```

Comment: You allocated a memory region like this, let's say `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` by using the `malloc`. `Malloc` will return a pointer to the first position of the allocated memory, that is, `*ptr = [0]`. Even though you may have 1 thousand pointers pointing to any memory region between 0-4 (that has been allocated), when you free the memory, you must free using the first address of the allocated region. For instance, if you have 10 pointers pointing to the first address of the allocated memory region, only one `free` is enough. I hope I could be clear.

Comment: To be more clear, thing as 1 `malloc` implies 1 `free`, that is, 1-to-1 "mapping".

Comment: What is `myArr`?  FYI: `miniArray` is pointing to memory, but not the beginning of the allocation, so the commented out `free(miniArray)` would fail.

Comment: The rule is simple: Free exactly once for each allocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `parentArray` is the value returned by `malloc` and this is the value that needs to be passed to `free`. The family of functions in C that perform dynamic memory allocation are: `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc`. Calling `free` on a value not returned by one of these functions or calling `free` on the same value twice is undefined behavior.

There do exist other functions such as `strdup` that call `malloc` and return the result, so these pointers must be freed too. The documentation for `strdup` will tell you this. In general when writing C you must understand who is responsible for allocating and freeing memory and make sure this "contract" is well documented.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity. Is there an exact reason for that? Are those the only three functions' products that can be passed into free?

Comment: Yeah. Those are your 3 functions in C that allocate dynamic memory. There do exist other functions such as `strdup` that call `malloc` and return the result, so these pointers must be freed too. The documentation for `strdup` will tell you this. In general when writing C you must understand who is responsible for allocating and freeing memory and make sure this "contract" is well documented.

Comment: You may want to edit your question and move some of the information from your comment above into the answer -- to insure it is not overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

```
char * miniArray   = &parentArray [1];
```

Here you're not allocating memory, instead you're just making `miniArray` point to some address.

There is no need for `free` for `miniArray` hence.

However dereferecing `miniArray` **should not** be done after `free(parentArray)`. That results in undefined behavior, ie you should not do

`*miniArray`

later in your code.

Answer (score 1):

`free()` deallocates the space previously allocated by `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()` otherwise the behavior is undefined.

From C Standard##7.22.3.3p2

> The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the behavior is undefined.

In your code snippet, `parentArray` is allocated memory using `malloc()` 
 but here:

```
char * miniArray   = &parentArray [1];
```

`miniArray` is pointing to address of the first element of `parentArray` which is a valid memory but not the pointer returned by `malloc()`. Hence, calling free for `miniArray` would be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

1. `parentArray` references dynamic memory allocated by `malloc()`; nothing else your code snippet does.
2. Each allocation provided by `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()` should be freed once and only once; multiple references to the same allocation must only be freed once.

A brief example:

```
void *a=malloc(size); // a references heap mem allocation
void *b=a; // b references heap mem allocation
free(a);   // heap mem allocation freed
free(b);   // error: heap mem allocation already freed
```